# Finding Multiple Files, Copying, and Renaming Sequentially

Tags: bash

I have a few hundred thousand files in many, many subdirectories. I am trying to extract all of the relevant image files, using a regular expression like so:

```
find -E . -regex '.+\.ca/.+(\.gif|\.jpg|\.tif|\.jpeg|\.tiff|\.png|\.jp2|\.j2k|\.bmp|\.pict|\.wmf|\.emf|\.ico|\.xbm)'
```

This finds the files. However, I want to move them to a `newdir` and have them named like so:

```
1.png  
2.jpg  
3.ico  
4.pict  
5.png
```

And so forth. I haven't been able to find a way that (a) preserves the various extensions; (b) renames them as they come in. Many of the files will be duplicates and I will want to preserve that. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do this purely in bash? I think your life will be much easier if you try to code this in something like Python with appropriate calls to bash commands like the `find` above

Comment: @Phani Mostly just personal comfort, to be completely honest, although you may have a good point here. Am running Barmar's script below, seems to be working so far. :)

Comment: @Phani This isn't nearly complex enough to be `much easier` in python.

Comment: agreed. I wouldn't have posted this if I've seen Barmar's answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
i=1
find ... | while read filename; do
    newname=$i.${filename##*.}
    mv "$filename" newdir/"$newname"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```